# determine the addressability knowing the address space

Tags: memory, memory-address, cpu-architecture

If we know the address space, are we able to compute the machine address-ability? For example, if the address space of a machine is 2^6 bits, what would the machine address-ability be?

Comment: What do you mean by "address-ability"? Are you talking about byte addressing vs word addressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a modern OS, memory space for each process is virtual. The system can manipulate with by far larger amounts of memory than the size of address space. Basically, adressability now only makes sense for a single process, which is limited by size of address space with some reserved regions subtracted.

For example, on Windows 32bit you have rougly 3,5 Gb of address space at process disposal.

We can't determine size of virtual memory available for a process from size of address space because size of reserved regions is OS specific.

Answer (score 2):

The hardware addressable memory and the virtual address space size are two different things. In most processors, the hardware addressable range is significantly smaller than than the virtual addresses size. There are some processors (generally using some kind of segmentation) where the hardware addressable range is larger than the virtual (or programable) address space size.